# How can I set locale by cookies in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, internationalization, locale

I am currently making my website internationally and I thought I didn't want to change the URL to change locale or add the parameter of the locale to URL because there are a lot of pages.
So, I am trying to use cookies to change the locale.
And I wonder if this is possible in the first place.
the steps I came up with was this.

1: in view, set two links, one is English and the other is Polish.

2: when choosing the language, the data of the locale saves in cookies.

3: once the user chooses the language, other pages that the user visits written in the language the user chose.

If those above are possible, please tell me how.

Comment: I've never used this, but there is a project: https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator that looks very interesting.  it appears to rename the objects in the route, as well as providing language support.

Comment: URL locals are often better for UX as I might send a page to a friend in my local and they don't have the cookie. Also, for setting the default locale consider the `accept-language` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As one of the solutions you can pass locale through your links with params. But you need to make some changes in your `ApplicationController` (see code comments):

```rb
before_action :set_locale

# Method for change URL helpers
def default_url_options
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end

def set_locale
  if params[:locale].present?
    cookies.permanent[:locale] = params[:locale] # save cookies
  end

  locale = cookies[:locale]&.to_sym # read cookies

  if I18n.available_locales.include?(locale)
    I18n.locale = locale # use cookies locale
  end
end
```

And for example change your `routes.rb` this way:

```
scope '(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join('|')}/ do
  # your routes here
end
```

Now you can use links to current page with passing locales as params like:

```
<%= link_to 'PL', url_for(locale: :pl) %>
<%= link_to 'EN', url_for(locale: :en) %>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
with your advice, I finally made my website accessible in two languages.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible without a problem. You can [load cookie values on server-side](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html) without much issues and you could use a lng/language or whatever name you choose. Hopefully you generate your HTML files rather than statically render them. If so, then you can use a data structure that would be essentially an array, containing languages and each language item would contain a set of key-value pairs, where the key would be the message's name and the value would be the message value.

Example:

- you have an array of two items, "en" and "pl"
- the items are hashes
- both items have the same keys
- each item has a "greeting" key in its hash
- the "greeting" for the "pl" item is "Polak, Węgier, dwa bratanki, i do szabli, i do szklanki" (the only Polish saying I know) and for the "en" you would have the English version of the same saying
- you would operate similarly with all texts

Now, whether you render your page on server-side or on client-side, you will somehow need to have a way to read from this array and when you read from it, know what is the chosen language.

As about changing cookies on client-side, you can easily do it, like

```
 document.cookie = "lng=pl";
```

You will need to wrap an event around this, like a click on a flag or something, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you so much for teaching.
it helps me a lot.